# Column Type for User Fields

Tags: list, document-library, outlook

Can you change the default column type from *Single line of text* to *Person or group* on the User Fields in List Settings?

Answer (score 3):

No you can not change *Single line of text* to *Person or group*.

[image]

But you can change it to

- *Multiple lines of text*
- *Choice (menu to choose from)*
- *Number (1, 1.0, 100)*
- *Currency ($, ¥, €)*
- *Date and Time*

Workaround

- *Delete and create again manually or using PowerShell.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be change. Get into the column properties and change it.